# Oracle ADF ViewCriteria cancel

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

How it is possible to cancel/reject applied ViewCriteria,

lets say I have view criteria which I want to apply to view object but later I want to reject this view criteria to make view object be displayed in it's default state.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing the following:

```
viewObject.getViewCriteriaManager().clearViewCriterias();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
ViewObjectImpl sampleVO = this.getSample();
sampleVO.getViewCriteriaManager().removeApplyViewCriteriaName(vcName);
sampleVO.executeQuery();
```